# How to de-serialize XML with many child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

If my XML is like this:

```
<Item>
    <Name>Jerry</Name>
    <Array>
        <Item>
            <Name>Joe</Name>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>Sam</Name>
        </Item>
    </Array>
</Item>
```

I can serialize it into this class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "dict")]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Array")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But what if my XML is like this?

```
<Item>
    <Name>Jerry</Name>
    <Item>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Sam</Name>
    </Item>
</Item>
```

This does not work:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "Item")]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Item")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**What is the right way to decorate the class?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want control over xml, then `XmlSerializer` is the way to go, not `DataContractSerializer`. The latter simply lacks the fine-grained control that `XmlSerializer` offers; in this case for things like list/array layout - but even just *xml attributes* are a problem for `DataContractSerializer`. Then it is just:

```
public class Item {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Item {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
var item = (Item) serializer.Deserialize(source);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect that this is on WP7 to matter. But System.Xml.XmlSerializer is not part of WP7, it turns out. Suggestion?

Comment: My main suggestion would be : mention the platform in the question. DCS has problems here, simply. You might have to drop to manual parsing. Does WP7 support LINQ-to-XML? If so, I'd use that.

Comment: No, but I can't change my downvote to an upvote unless you edit the question :)

Comment: `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` **is part of WP7**. You need to add a reference to System.Xml.Serialization.dll to be able to use it.

Comment: @Jerry please note carlosfigueira's comment that XmlSerializer is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CollectionDataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx)
Internally you should create a generic list of Items and decorate it as CollectionDataContractAttribute with appropriate parameters.