# load xml file and read tag windows store app c#

Tags: xml, serialization, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to load my xml file in my app and read just specific tags from my xml. Can someone help me? I have tried couple of things but all I get is the full xml text, not the specific tags.

This is the code:

```cs
 try
 {
     StorageFolder storageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
     StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("players2.xml");

     XmlTextBlock.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     XmlTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
 }
```

and my xml is:

```xml
<player>
<name>Ricardo Ferreira Rodrigues</name>
<shirtnumber>1</shirtnumber>
</player>
```

I want to see the results in txtname and txtshirtnumber. Someone can help?

Comment: Look at using LINQ to XML (XElement, XDocument etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon commented, you should read about [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb387098.aspx). It's the best (easiest and most powerful) way to handle XML structures in .NET.

Your document is quite simple, so the queries are simple too:

```cs
// parse the xml into XDocument instance
var doc = XDocument.Parse(XmlTextBlock.Text);

// query for <name> and <shirtnumber> and assign values to proper textboxes
txtname.Text = (string)doc.Root.Element("name");
txtshirtnumber.Text = (string)doc.Root.Element("shirtnumber");
```

Comment: Root element is missing. why?

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would deserialize the XML directly into a class.

[How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

```cs
string path = "file.xml";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var x = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

reader.Close();
```

[C# XML Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220973/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization?rq=1)

```cs
[XmlRoot("Document", Namespace = "")]
public partial class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[How to de-serialize XML with many child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219700/how-to-de-serialize-xml-with-many-child-nodes)

http://www.stepupframeworks.com/Home/products/xml-object-mapping-xom/